# Changing Dynamically Added Tab Text Color- Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabactivity

Hi I am adding tabs dynamically in my Android application, In that I just want to change the text color in the tab. I tried several methods like applying styles. But none works for me. Can anyone tell me the ways to achieve this.

```
 for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {

        // final int tabCount = bar.getTabCount();
        final String text = unit[k];
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText(text)

                .setTabListener(new TabListener(new TabContentFragment(text))));
//bar.getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.tabcolor);
    }
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the text color of a dynamically added tab, just add this line in your theme.

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabtextcolor</item>
```